# htaccess replace part of url based on condition

Tags: .htaccess

I'd like to redirect from a URL like `http://www.example.de/this.xml`

To the `.xml` with the right language, eg. `http://www.example.de/this-www.example.de.xml`

The same with every other language i.e. (de|com|eu ...)

Right now I've got this, but I don't know how to set the right language in the `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.(de|at|ch|com|nl|be|fr)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/this.xml$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /this-www.mydomain.$1(de|at|ch|com|nl|be|fr)$2.xml [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to specifically check for the ccTLD? It looks like you are simply copying the *host* into the target URL-path?

Try something like the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(this)(\.xml)$ /$1-%{HTTP_HOST}$2 [R=301,L]
```

This will permanently redirect a request for `http://www.example.de/this.xml` to `http://www.example.de/this-www.example.de.xml`.

Note that if you've previously been testing with 301s you will need to make sure that any intermediary caches are cleared since any earlier *erroneous* 301s will have been cached. (Testing with 302s can sometimes be beneficial for this reason.)

---

> But how would you have checked specifically for the ccTLD?

To allow only a select few ccTLDs and also capture the TLD from the *host* then you would need to use a `RewriteCond` directive and check against the `HTTP_HOST` server variable, similar to what you have done. However, your `RewriteRule` *substitution* is wrong.

For example, you could do something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.(de|at|ch|com|nl|be|fr)$
RewriteRule ^(this)(\.xml)$ /$1-%2$2 [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect `http://www.example.de/this.xml` to `http://www.example.de/this-de.xml`. But not do anything with `http://www.example.us/this.xml`, since the ccTLD does not match one of those in the *CondPattern*.

`$1` and `$2` are backreferences to the captured groups in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. Whereas `%2` is a backreference to the 2nd captured group in the last matched `RewriteCond` *CondPattern*.

NB: You should canonicalise the domain (ie. redirect to www or non-www) earlier in your config, so that making `www.` optional in the above regex (ie. `(www\.)?`) should not be necessary.

Comment: Yes, I simply copied the host into the target URL-path.

Thank you for help, it works like intended.

But how would you have checked specifically for the ccTLD?